# Get Json Object using spray.json

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

I'm using spray and I need to return a `json` object through a method.

```
val route = 

path("all-modules") {
        get {
          respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) {
            complete( configViewer.findAllModules.toString)
          }
        }
      }
```

This prints `ConfigResults(S1000,Success,List(testDataTypes, mandate, sdp))`

But I need get this as the `json` object. how can I do it?

I tried in this way

```
 val route =

    path("all-modules") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          complete{
            configViewer.findAllModules
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

It gives an compilation error `could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller`

Comment: Btw. you usually don't need to use the `respondWithMediaType` directive. The marshaller will automatically figure out which content type to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Spray how it should serialize your case class.

Just configure something like

```
object JsonSupport {
    implicit val formatConfigResults = jsonFormat3(ConfigResults)
}
```

The number in jsonFormat'number' stands for the number of members in your case class.

Then you just need to import into your route, the class where you define this implicit.

```
import JsonSupport._
```

Comment: If this is about spray-json it needs an `import DefaultJsonProtocol._` and an additional `import SprayJsonSupport._` in the routing file.